# How popular was the Canon X-07?

Tags: canon

I have this beast, the Canon X-07:

[image]

The product by itself was of high quality, Z80 and RS-232 compatible and with a lot of peripherals available such as:

- thermal printer
- 4 colors tracer
- infrared interface
- video interface for TV output
- tape interface
- memory cards
- application cards

There is quite some literature about it on the Internet and even emulators, however, little about how widespread its use was.

How popular was the computer back then when it was released in 1984 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual it depends on what popular should mean, which usage area is ment to be used and what region of the world we are talking about.

While smaler, it's fair to classify the X-07 as a typical member of the A4/letter sized portable/laptop computers. The most prominent family here are the Kyotronic 85 family (Kyotronic 85, NEC 8201/8300, Olivetti M10, Tandy M100/M102) as well as the Epson HX-20 and Casio's FP200. The X-07 as a late comer to that market.

AFAIK it got most use in Japan and some parts of Asia, much less in Europe, and comparable little in the US. Being quite late (1985, *1) the market was already quite saturated with other models - which in addition often offered larger screens and a greater software selection to the user. In addition, 1984/5 already brought the next generation, like the Tandy 200, while the market at whole started moving toward units more like today's laptops (80 character per line displays, x86 CPU, etc.).

Canon tried to position it as low end device for people who would not like to afford the 'bigger' ones and got some success at the low end/hobbyist market.

Judging form how often French language sites come up [when searching](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/7806/how-popular-was-the-canon-x-07/7816#comment22329_7816) for the X-07, it might have had a good sale in France or French speaking countries in general.

---

*1 - 1985 in Europe (1984 in Japan). That's three years after the HX-20 (1982) and two years after the various Kyotronics (1983).

Comment: The X-07 must have been pretty popular in France, considering the number of French mentions on retro sites, as well as the amount of literature for this machine available in French.

Comment: Thanks, actually it's rather half A4 than a full size page (200x130x30mm).

Comment: @Aybe yes it is. Then again, it does differ from the usual hand-helds like Casio PB-770, Sharp PC1250, TI 74 or HP75. Most important by using a more standard (Z80) alike CPU, buch like the bigger ones.  I guess we can find many reasons to put it in either cathegory.

Comment: That makes it sort of an UFO in the world of personal computers :)

Comment: "It depends on what popular should mean..."  Yeah, the OP should have been clearer about what is being asked.